# Installing GAMS API for Python not successful

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, gams-math

I installed the API exactly as mentioned on this  [Tutorial](https://www.gams.com/latest/docs/API_PY_TUTORIAL.html#PY_GETTING_STARTED) and no error happened. but when I type: `import gams` on my ide (idle), the following error shows up:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import gams
  File "C:\Users\Mansour\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\gams\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .workspace import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

I'm using GAMS 25.0.2 and python 3.6.5 on windows 10. everything is 64-bit.
p.s this is the log from cmd when installing the API:

```
C:\GAMS\win64\25.0\apifiles\Python\api_36>python setup.py install
running install
running build
running build_py
running install_lib
running install_egg_info
Removing C:\Users\Mansour\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages\gamsemb-0.0.0-py3.6.egg-info
Writing C:\Users\Mansour\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages\gamsemb-0.0.0-py3.6.egg-info
running install
running build
running build_py
running install_lib
running install_egg_info
Removing C:\Users\Mansour\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages\gdxcc-7-py3.6.egg-info
Writing C:\Users\Mansour\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages\gdxcc-7-py3.6.egg-info
running install
running build
running build_py
running install_lib
running install_egg_info
Removing C:\Users\Mansour\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages\gamsxcc-1-py3.6.egg-info
Writing C:\Users\Mansour\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages\gamsxcc-1-py3.6.egg-info
running install
running build
running build_py
running install_lib
running install_egg_info
Removing C:\Users\Mansour\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages\dctmcc-1-py3.6.egg-info
Writing C:\Users\Mansour\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages\dctmcc-1-py3.6.egg-info
running install
running build
running build_py
running install_lib
running install_egg_info
Removing C:\Users\Mansour\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages\gevmcc-6-py3.6.egg-info
Writing C:\Users\Mansour\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages\gevmcc-6-py3.6.egg-info
running install
running build
running build_py
running install_lib
running install_egg_info
Removing C:\Users\Mansour\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages\gmomcc-16-py3.6.egg-info
Writing C:\Users\Mansour\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages\gmomcc-16-py3.6.egg-info
running install
running build
running build_py
running install_lib
running install_egg_info
Removing C:\Users\Mansour\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages\cfgmcc-1-py3.6.egg-info
Writing C:\Users\Mansour\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages\cfgmcc-1-py3.6.egg-info
running install
running build
running build_py
running install_lib
running install_egg_info
Removing C:\Users\Mansour\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages\gmdcc-2-py3.6.egg-info
Writing C:\Users\Mansour\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages\gmdcc-2-py3.6.egg-info
running install
running build
running build_py
running install_lib
running install_egg_info
Removing C:\Users\Mansour\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages\optcc-2-py3.6.egg-info
Writing C:\Users\Mansour\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages\optcc-2-py3.6.egg-info
running install
running build
running build_py
running install_lib
running install_egg_info
Removing C:\Users\Mansour\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages\GAMS-1.0-py3.6.egg-info
Writing C:\Users\Mansour\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages\GAMS-1.0-py3.6.egg-info
```

Answer (score 0):

After trying everything, I found out that my GAMS is 64-bit but I had python 3.6 32-bit installed. Everything works fine by installing python 3.6 64-bit